# Discrete Cosine Transform Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, math, multidimensional-array, equation

I'm trying to implement the 2D Cosine Transform equation given under the Discrete Cosine Transform section of this webpage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

```
    public void transform() {
        int u;
        int v;
        double alphau;
        double alphav;

        double[][] test = {
            {52, 55, 61, 66, 70, 61, 64, 73},   
            {63, 59, 55, 90, 109, 85, 69, 72},
            {62, 59, 68, 113, 144, 104, 66, 73},
            {63, 58, 71, 122, 154, 106, 70, 69}, 
            {67, 61, 68, 104, 126, 88, 68, 70},  
            {79, 65, 60, 70, 77, 68, 58, 75},
            {85, 71, 64, 59, 55, 61, 65, 83},
            {87, 79, 69, 68, 65, 76, 78, 94}
        };

        double summation = 0;
        double[][] coefficients = new double[8][8];

        for(int x = 0; x < test.length; x++) 
        {

            for(int y = 0; y < test[x].length; y++)
            {
                //Inner discrete transform.
                u = x % 8;
                v = y % 8;

                double cosu = Math.cos(Math.toRadians((((2 * x) + 1) * u * Math.PI) / 16));
                double cosv = Math.cos(Math.toRadians((((2 * y) + 1) * v * Math.PI) / 16));

                summation = ((test[y][x]) * cosu * cosv) + summation;
                System.out.print(test[y][x] - 128 + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        System.out.println("");

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
            {
                //Outer discrete transform.
                alphau = 1.0;
                alphav = 1.0;

                if(i == 0) {
                    alphav = 1 / Math.sqrt(2);
                }
                if(j == 0) {
                    alphau = 1 / Math.sqrt(2);
                }

                coefficients[i][j] = .25 * alphau * alphav * summation;

                System.out.print(coefficients[i][j] + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
```

A quick link to the equation I am trying to implement can be found here: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx3KL.png)
The first for loop is meant to calculate the double summation of the cosines of the test array while the second is meant to multiply it with its respective alpha values. 
My output for the coefficients returns :

589, 833, 833, 833, 833, 833, 833, 833, 
833, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 
833, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 
833, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 
833, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 
833, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 
833, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 
833, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179, 1179,

While the expected output can be found here: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/immYL.png)

Answer (score 0):

The out of the following program matches to the online DCT calculator
https://asecuritysite.com/comms/dct2
Please check and let me know if this works for you

```
 void dctTransform(double matrix[][])
    {
        int i, j, k, l;

        // dct will store the discrete cosine transform
        double[][] dct = new double[m][n];

        double ci, cj, dct1, sum;

        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                // ci and cj depends on frequency as well as
                // number of row and columns of specified matrix
                if (i == 0)
                    ci = 1 / Math.sqrt(m);
                else
                    ci = Math.sqrt(2) / Math.sqrt(m);

                if (j == 0)
                    cj = 1 / Math.sqrt(n);
                else
                    cj = Math.sqrt(2) / Math.sqrt(n);

                // sum will temporarily store the sum of
                // cosine signals
                sum = 0;
                for (k = 0; k < m; k++)
                {
                    for (l = 0; l < n; l++)
                    {
                        dct1 = matrix[k][l] *
                                Math.cos((2 * k + 1) * i * pi / (2 * m)) *
                                Math.cos((2 * l + 1) * j * pi / (2 * n));
                        sum = sum + dct1;
                    }
                }
                dct[i][j] = ci * cj * sum;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                System.out.printf("%f\t", dct[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code worked. I'm still confused why the logic for my code doesn't give the same results though. It seems like your code and the code on the website is just better optimized for larger 2-D arrays, right?

Comment: yes @DurgaDarba If think the solution is right let me know

Comment: Your solution is correct. Where did I go wrong in the code I provided?